# \dirtree builds but gives error

Tags: texstudio, dirtree

I am trying to build a \dirtree in my document. I get an error and I can't figure out what is wrong.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,fleqn,openright]{book}
\usepackage{dirtree}

\begin{document}

\dirtree{%
    .1. Dokumenti.
    .2 FS.
    .3 CV.
    .4 \vdots.
    .4 SET\_IBKDAGL.txt.
    .4 SET\_IBKDAGL\_HRAPAVE.txt.
    .4 SET\_IBKDAGD.txt.
    .4 SET\_IBKDAGD\_HRAPAVE.txt.
    .4 \vdots.
}

\end{document}
```

I am using TeXsudio. It builds but I get an error.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found the mistake.

The problem is when stating the firs level of the directory:

```
.1. dir.
```

it should be:

```
.1 dir.
```

There was a extra fullstop at .1. instead of .1